# Checking for Operators in Java

Tags: java, stack, operator-precedence, postfix-notation

I was writing a code for infix to postfix conversion. However I'm unable to find a method to check for operators like (,),+,- etc. I could use ASCII but is there any method (like isLetter() etc) which I could use?Also how can i define the operator precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . I could use ASCII but is there any method (like isLetter() etc)
>   which I could use?

Well I can suggest you `Character.isDigit('1')` or `Character.isLetter('A')` for checking whether this character is digit or letter but as customization I will go for `ArrayList`.

```
    ArrayList<Character> alist=new ArrayList<>();
    alist.add('+');
    alist.add('-');
    alist.add('/');
    alist.add('%');
    char c='A';
    if(alist.contains(c))
    {
        System.out.println("UNREACHABLE");
    }
```

Secondly for operator precedence you can use

`HashMap<Character, Integer> hm=new HashMap<>();`

```
hmap.put('+',1);
```

with key and value pair to determine it's precedence

Answer (score 0):

You can try the getType function in the Character class. It also has many constants to check against, eg: MATH_SYMBOL.

Character class also has methods like isDigit, isLetter etc too.

More info:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28int%29)